# How to symlink /Library/Frameworks/Python.frameowork/Versions/7.3/bin into /usr/local

Tags: enthought

Is there a way to have all the `packages/folders/etc` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/bin` symlinked into `/usr/local` to make it like other python installations?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ln -s  source-directory  destination-directory
```